# PHP not working after debian dist-upgrade

Tags: linux, debian, upgrade, php, dist-upgrade

I recently upgraded from debian 10.10 to 11
My website had stopped working properly.
It was showing php code instead of actual formatted page
Thinking that It was due to not-working apache2 with php I did following

```
a2enmod
```

it showed php7.4 module
I activated it
Everything started working
Any Idea about how this can be prevented during dist-upgrade?

Comment: do the same thing every time you upgrade

Comment: An upgrade from Debian 10's PHP 7.3 to 11's PHP 7.4 means there are [some incompatible changes in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php), so you'll need to check your PHP apps/scripts for compatibility. The manual step to enable PHP 7.4 will remind you to pay attention to this.